# Defining app name in a single file and apply it all page as variable php with this folder stucture

Tags: php

I have some files in folders look like `first_folder/inner_folder/myfile.php` and `second_folder/yourfile.php`, now all these folders found in  `C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp`

The problem:

I want to include the file `yourfile.php` in the `myfile.php` look the contents in both files below

yourfile.php HAVE

```
<?php 
$app = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/myapp';
?>
```

myfile.php HAVE

```
<?php 
include_once('yourfile.php');
include_once($app.'/helper/another.php');
?>
```

The problem start from here

```
include_once('yourfile.php');
```

The above line do not work unless I change it as follow

```
include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/myapp/yourfile.php');
```

Question:

What if i have many file which require `yourfile.php` again what if they changed app name from myapp to another name in the yourfile.php

Help help!

Comment: The only way this will work 'include_once('yourfile.php')' is if the page you are loading is in the 'second_folder'.  I don't see how this works 'include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/myapp/yourfile.php')' because it should be 'include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/myapp/second_folder/yourfile.php')'.

Comment: If you are using classes and namespaces, PSR-4 is a very good start.

Comment: Also, in PHP the '/' character is the same as '$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']'.  So you could write '/myapp/first-folder/xxx.php' instead.

Comment: @NigelRen can you explain it, because I dont want that app name to appear